# I am trying to maximize the following constrained optimization and I need help.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

$$ \arg \max\limits_{C,D} \quad tr\{C^{-1}D\} + \log(det(C)) - \log(det(D)) \\
  \mbox{sub. to} \quad tr\{C\} \le k \\
                 \quad \quad D > 0 $$

I did the following. Rewrite the above optimization problem as:

$$ \arg \max\limits_{C,D} \quad tr\{C^{-1}D\} - \log(det(C^{-1}D)) \\
  \mbox{sub. to} \quad tr\{C\} \le k \\
                 \quad \quad D > 0 $$

Since $D > 0$, let $D = GG^H$ and $F = G^H C^{-1} G$.

This gives $det(C^{-1}D) = det(D)/det(C) = det(GG^H)/det(C) = det(F)$.

Also, $C = GF^{-1}G^H$. Our new optimization problem is the following

$$ \arg \max\limits_{G,F} \quad tr\{ F \} - \log(det(F)) \\ 
   \mbox{sub. to} \quad tr\{ GF^{-1}G^H \} \le k$$

Without the constraint, I know that the optimization problem is unbounded. With the constraint, how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem without the constraint.  If the constraint is violated, you know the constraint must be 'active'.  In other words, can replace the less-than-or-equal with an equal.  Suppose that your constraint is violated (the opposite is a simple solution.).  You have the following relationships.

$$
arg \max_{G,F} tr\{F\}−log(det(F)) \\
tr\{GF^{−1}GH\}=k
$$

The first statement is equivalent to the derivative being zero and its double derivative being negative.  That is the partials of course.

$$
\delta_G \left( tr\{F\}−log(det(F))\right)=0 \\
\delta_F \left( tr\{F\}−log(det(F))\right)=0 \\
tr\{GF^{−1}GH\}=k\\
\delta_G^2 \left( tr\{F\}−log(det(F))\right)<0 \\
\delta_F^2 \left( tr\{F\}−log(det(F))\right)<0 \\
$$

Solve the first three equations and verify the last two are satisfied.

Comment: Note that the partials can be separated like so because the the equation is only dependent on F.  Otherwise, the sum would be equal to zero.  Similarly for the double partials.

Comment: Without the constraints, the maximization is unbounded. This can be shown by considering $F = TT^H$, where $T$ is a lower triangular matrix. I was hoping the constraint would make it a bounded function.

Comment: Well if the unconstrained solution violates the constraint, then the constraint does keep the solution bounded. Have you checked this?